# Why Date_Format() not working correctly?

Tags: mysql

I am using following query to show Gross and Net Amount Month & Year-wise:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(BILLDATE,'MMM-yyyy'), SUM(GROSSAMOUNT), SUM(NETAMOUNT) 
FROM BILLDETAILS GROUP BY MONTH(BILLDATE);
```

Other columns are displayed correctly except the first one that involves Date_Format. It is displaying MMM-yyyy in all rows instead of the actual Month and Year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `'MMM-yyyy'` is not a correct date format. You probably want `'%b-%Y'`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format